# Shortest path to collect N items algorithm

Tags: graph, shortest-path

On a 2 dimensional rectangular field there are a bunch of items. I want to collect N items (there can be more or less than N items on the field, if less than N items, it should collect all items) and the starting node can be anywhere on the field. I can get the coordinates of all the items and the starting node on the field. I want it also return to the starting point. How can I calculate the path so that I travel the shortest distance possible?[image]

Comment: Strat BFS from the origin (current location) until you find the first item. Start BFS from the first item location until you find the second item and so on. Stop when you have collected N items or when all field was explored.

Comment: This is a viable solution the problem I have ran into it with though is that if the closest node is the opposite direction of every other node. Thanks for the suggestion though! @c0der